# How to get EmailId from JourneyId using Marketing Cloud REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, journeybuilder

I am looking for static email preview (without replacing placeholders).
I have JourneyId, how do i get EmailId associated with the Journey using Marketing Cloud REST API. 
So that i can retrieve email content using email id(one of the api i know for this is : https://www.exacttargetapis.com/guide/v1/emails/[emailid]/preview?kind=html,text)

Thanks,
Amit